# Remove Category Base for single custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove category base for particular custom post in wordpress permalinks. I used `WP No Category Base` plugin but this was working for all.

Comment: Check here, hope it might help you : http://wpgarage.com/code-snippets/remove-permalink-base-custom-post-type-slug/

Comment: Please don't mark your questions as urgent - detailed, well-researched questions should garner replies in due course. I'll add the `php` tag.

Comment: Refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite

Comment: My problem is solved by changing rewrite slug in function file. Thanks for reply. :) And Special thanks to @Jenis Patel

Comment: most welcome :) @SoniaSarangal